# Android to Raspberry Pi with TCP/IP

Tags: java, android

I'm working on creating an Android app that will act as a controller for a robot I'm building for my kids. I just want to be able to turn it's head, and move it's arms. I was experimenting with TCP/IP earlier, and was able to send data from my phone to my Raspi. The issue I'm confused about is how to go about parsing the data. Currently, I'm just dumping all of the data into one stream from the phone, is there any way to send data for the head turn, and the individual arms as separate streams, and then send them off to the robot?

Comment: Exactly what kind of data are you dumping into the stream ? Do you send out the data when the seekbar is moved and comes to rest ? Or do you keep sending out a packet every time the seekbar moves a little ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use any popular format like JSON or XML for this like

```
{"command":{"type":"head","direction":{"up":"2","down":"0","left":"0","right":"0"}}}
```

And parse it in the RPi

Comment: I have seekbars used for the movements, not sure how to do that with XML, I want to use the phone like a remote control. I'm thinking maybe I need to create multiple ports, and assign a port to each seekbar?